# Echoing table contents

Tags: php, beginner, mysql

I'm working on an exercise where I"m supposed to display all data contained in a table.  Here's the solution I can up with:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY id DESC");
    while($user= mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $user['first'] . " " . $user['last'] . "<br />" . $user[phone] . "br />";
    }
?>
```

Here's the solution the tutorial gave:

```
<?php 
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY id DESC");

$num=mysql_num_rows($result); 

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$first=mysql_result($result,$i,"first");
$last=mysql_result($result,$i,"last");
$phone=mysql_result($result,$i,"phone");


echo "<b>$first $last</b><br>Phone: $phone<br><hr><br>";

$i++;
}
?>
```

The database fields are:

```
id
first
last
phone
```

Can someone explain WHY one is better than the other. They both work as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yours is better.  Both are bad.

### Don't use either of them

The mysql_* functions aren't a good way to learn how to interact with databases.  It is a shame that there are still tutorials teaching how to interact with databases using these functions.  Here is a snippet that explains more about why you shouldn't use those functions and what you can use instead:

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).
> <sub>[Snippet Source](https://gist.github.com/3881905)</sub>

### Minor Comments

You missed quotes around phone.

In pure PHP don't use an end tag `?>`.  It can cause output if you have blank lines after it causing headers to be sent prematurely (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/php-closing-tag)).

Comment: Hi @paul, thanks for the response.  I've saved all the links you've provided and will work on the PDO tutorial you provided.  Is my understanding correct that PDO & MYSQLi strictly relate to accessing and manipulating database data and are not another method of writing PHP?

Comment: PDO & mysqli are both extensions to PHP which are included with the standard installation in PHP > 5.1.  Both are just for accessing databases.  I like PDO because it also works with non-mysql databases.

Comment: @NewToCode - Another note: don't use `SELECT *` for anything. Always list the columns you want to get from the database. That way, if the structure of the table changes you can catch it as a database error (which it is) rather than have your code roll on assuming it has all the data it expects when in fact it does not.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it as an exercise but still it is good to pay attention to your sql queries. This is where it gains/loose performance (let's assume your `contacts` table has more than 100000 contacts ).

Here you have `"SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC"`. First thing, do you really need that `order by` clause? if not, then remove it else make sure that `id` column in `contacts` table is indexed. Note that sort is always expensive.

`order by id` can also be achieved in php side using a custom sort algorithm or php sort function. However mysql sort wins over php sort whereas I believe it is opposite in case of java.

Comment: During the learning stage is way to earlier to be paranoid about performance (though I do agree that the sort seems odd).  Also, as for your last paragraph, that could be a rather bad idea.  If you already happen to have the data in memory, yeah, sure, I suppose sorting application side might not be a bad idea, but pulling the data from the DB and then immediately sorting could have huge performance implications.  Tree-based indexes can be walked in order in linear time (compared to nlgn sorting), and try doing ORDER BY col LIMIT 10, 30 without pulling the entire table.

Comment: Ok. I agree with you.